# Regarding Datepicker in Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am trying to achieve a separate date picker in angular material,
I need a separate date picker for date, month and year in angular material. How to achieve it

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried in angular material, we have date picker tag in it, but there we need to select combinely, but I need a separate picker to click on dates(1-31), Month(Jan-Dec) and years.